# Cant push or pull on github

Tags: git, push, pull

I am new at this. I was doing OK untill I try to "`git push`" and this is what i get on command line:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

After that, I tried to "`git pull`" and it refuses to merge and this is what the command says:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

What are my options at this point?

Comment: You have to pull first merge code and push on remote

Comment: git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories

Comment: If you don’t want merging code than discard local changes and than pull origin master

Comment: thank you guys for the help, will try it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are pushing to a new repository where a README or LICENSE file was created automatically, that would mean:

- you have a local history of commits on your computer
- you have a remote (very short) history of commits (most like one) in your new remote repository

That would explain the "unrelated history" part: those two branch (local master and remote master) have no commits in common.

If (and only if) that is the case (meaning it is your first push to a brand new remote repository), then you can consider simply force pushing: `git push --force`.
But if it is not the case (meaning the remote repo has a long history of commits), then you would need to clone that repository in a new local folder, and report your current work in it.